# Computer crashes when streaming Team Fortress 2

Tags: windows-7, power-supply, crash

New computer. Played TF2 for 15 minutes, computer crashed and on boot it said something like
**PC shutdown because of power supply surge detected**. I fixed the problem by playing TF2 at the worst resolution. No more crashes.

Then I wanted to start streaming TF2 and I had to change the resolution back to 1920x1080 in order to stream and of course I got the same crashes. I disabled Asus anti surge in BIOS and the PSU surge crashes are gone but the computer still crashes when streaming TF2. And the crashes looks like this: http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=nef808%3E&s=8#.UxyGcvmS

I have tried both the latest beta Cataclyst drivers and the 13.12 drivers, which I currently run.
I have also tried two different Corsair PSUs listed in the specs.
I have ran stress test on the CPU, GPU and RAM. Temps was fine and no crashes.

i7 4770K
Z87-K
8GB 1333 MHz
120 GB SSD
500 GB HDD
Asus R9 280X
Corsair VS 550 / Corsair VS 650

Here are some stats the seconds before the computer crashes (Is 11.2V min voltage on the safe side or is that a too high voltage drop?): http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2gwrp7t%3E&s=8#.Ux40k_mSyHC

Sometimes this happens when I open an mp4 file or when I open a video on Youtube: tinypic.com/player.php?v=2qs032f&s=8#.Ux8k7_mSyHA

By the way, my computer draws around 300 W from the wall when I am streaming TF2.

Comment: Post driver details for the R9 card

Comment: I am using Cataclyst 13.12. Or do you mean this? http://i.imgur.com/g535GQP.png

Comment: The driver details indicates your using a driver released in June 2013 which makes no sense is you want BF4 support

Comment: The 13.12 drivers were released 12/18/2013. I have tried the latest beta drivers (14.2) which were released 2/25/2014, but they did not fix the problem.

Comment: Well the driver details say 6.12.2013... let me guess thats actually 12.6.2013 because of your system localization

Answer (score 0):

If accurate, you have two problems. Your +12V line is out of spec. It must always be [between 11.40 and 12.60 Volts](http://www.formfactors.org/developer/specs/ATX12V%20PSDG2.01.pdf), but is showing well below that voltage. Additionally, your mainboard is reporting a temperature of 111C, almost certainly much, much too hot. However, you may not want to trust that particular reading; [there are reports](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1797905/115c-mainboard-temperature-reading-hwmonitor.html) that HWMonitor, at least, provides bad results.

Your video card is [specified to require](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/R9280XDC2T3GD5/#specifications) 300 Watts of power over and above what the rest of your computer does. I'd have expected a 550 Watt power supply to be just about able to support the rest of your system, and 650 Watts should be plenty.

Comment: The mainboard temperature is probably false reading. It's showing over 100 ºC on idle and I have touched the NB and SB without burning myself. I can't smell any burning components either so I think that is a false reading. Well, let's say the PSU is the problem, how come my computer crashes when I start Youtube clips or mp4 files? That can't be because of the PSU. It does more look like driver or GPU errors... Right?

Comment: Because the more demanding the software the more power the card will require and YouTube isn't demanding

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I am trying to say... The PSU should not be the problem. But considering my +12V line dropped to 11.2V I guess the PSU might be the problem after all. But I don't think the PSU is the only problem, considering that the computer crashes when I open some Youtube clips or some mp4 files...

Comment: @user306917 - If your 12V is dropping down to 11.2v thats a power supply problem.